# Building / Installation NumPy

Tags: numpy, building

i want to work with NumPy. Now i'm trying to install NumPy on Windows. I do not understand, what i have to do to get it working. What does "building" mean? is there any difference between the installation and "building from source".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest approach to installing Numpy (and the rest of the Python 'scientific stack' including SciPy an many others) is to use Continuum Analytics' "Anaconda" tools.

http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#windows-install

Following these docs should get you everything you need.